# Looping through similar XML nodes/sub-nodes for XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am relatively new to XSL Transformations.

My input XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishVS_PPWO xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2019-11-15T11:55:15+11:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="2887862.1573779314727427868" maximoVersion="7 6 20170418-0100 V7608-61" event="1">
  <VS_PPWOSet>
    <WORKORDER action="Replace">
      <SITEID>SITE51</SITEID>
      <STATUS changed="1" maxvalue="COMP">COMP</STATUS>
      <STATUSDATE changed="1">2019-11-15T11:55:06+11:00</STATUSDATE>
      <WONUM>PW1024</WONUM>
      <FAILUREREPORT>
        <FAILURECODE>NDT</FAILURECODE>
        <FAILUREREPORTID>1704590</FAILUREREPORTID>
        <TYPE maxvalue="PROBLEM">PROBLEM</TYPE>
      </FAILUREREPORT>
      <FAILUREREPORT>
        <FAILURECODE>LINE</FAILURECODE>
        <FAILUREREPORTID>1704591</FAILUREREPORTID>
        <TYPE maxvalue="CAUSE">CAUSE</TYPE>
      </FAILUREREPORT>
      <FAILUREREPORT>
        <FAILURECODE>PASS</FAILURECODE>
        <FAILUREREPORTID>1704592</FAILUREREPORTID>
        <TYPE maxvalue="REMEDY">REMEDY</TYPE>
      </FAILUREREPORT>
    </WORKORDER>
  </VS_PPWOSet>
</PublishVS_PPWO>
```

XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:PublishVS_PPWO"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mea:PublishVS_PPWO">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:VS_PPWOSet"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mea:VS_PPWOSet">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:WORKORDER"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="mea:WORKORDER">
        <ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Operations>
                <Operation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <Object>
                        <Object xsi:type="Task">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:WONUM" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="formatDateTime">
                            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="mea:STATUSDATE" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                            <xsl:call-template name="TLS"></xsl:call-template>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='PROBLEM']/mea:FAILURECODE" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='CAUSE']/mea:FAILURECODE" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='REMEDY']/mea:FAILURECODE" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="TLS2"></xsl:call-template>
                        </Object>
                    </Object>
                </Operation>
            </Operations>   
        </ExecuteMultipleOperations>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mea:WONUM">
        <ExternalRefID><xsl:value-of select="." /></ExternalRefID>
        <Status>Completed</Status>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="formatDateTime">
     <xsl:param name="dateTime" />
     <xsl:variable name="date">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($dateTime, 'T')" />
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:variable name="time">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($dateTime, 'T'), '+')" />
     </xsl:variable>
     <CompletionDate><xsl:value-of select="concat($date,' ',$time)" /></CompletionDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="TLS">
     <TLSMissedAppointmentReason></TLSMissedAppointmentReason>
     <TLSMissedCommitmentReason></TLSMissedCommitmentReason>
     <TLSAction></TLSAction>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='PROBLEM']/mea:FAILURECODE">
        <TLSClearanceCode1><xsl:value-of select="." /></TLSClearanceCode1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='CAUSE']/mea:FAILURECODE">
        <TLSClearanceCode2><xsl:value-of select="." /></TLSClearanceCode2>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='REMEDY']/mea:FAILURECODE">
        <TLSClearanceCode3><xsl:value-of select="." /></TLSClearanceCode3>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="TLS2">
     <TLSRestorationTime></TLSRestorationTime>
     <TLSCompletionRemarks></TLSCompletionRemarks>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, output XML is unable to fetch the value of FAILURECODE.
So my question is whether mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='PROBLEM']/mea:FAILURECODE
is good enough to get to the value of FAILURECODE?

Any help is appreciated.

Please ignore the below :)
XSLT (eXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents, or other formats such as HTML for web pages, plain text or XSL Formatting Objects, which may subsequently be converted to other formats, such as PDF, PostScript and PNG.

Comment: Actually, this would work if the namespaces are defined in the right way. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to understand is whether  mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='PROBLEM']/mea:FAILURECODE will actually take me to the value of FAILURECODE?

Yes, my namespace are all defined in the right way

Comment: As far as I can deduce from your example, this should be the case.

Comment: but its not fetching the value of FAILURECODE and bringing it to the output XML

Comment: Its always empty in the output XML, so I suspect
mea:FAILUREREPORT[mea:TYPE='PROBLEM']/mea:FAILURECODE 
might not be enough to get to the value of FAILURECODE node

Comment: This is the sort of problem you get when you don't provide a [mcve] as requested by the conditions of StackOverflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58869780/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: @zx485  I have edited the question as requested. thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem that you report:https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNy9

Comment: Thanks guys, it did work indeed!

Comment: Hi guys, just a follow on question here



I only have one namespace defined in my XSL like this

 <ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">



So why do my output XML have 2 namespaces as below 

<ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">